# Caveats of highcharts-ng

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive, highcharts-ng

I read more about [highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) to use  directive, but they have many caveats.

I have two options:
- Use highcharts.js, then create my directives.
- Use highcharts-ng directive.

Please, What's the best way to use highcharts directive for angular, and If I use `highcharts-ng`, will I need some options, or features of highcharts, which didn't implement yet for `highcharts-ng` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way is to use highcharts-ng and edit it because they do almost every thing you need and they spend a lot of time to produce this directive and if you write your own directive you will waste your time

then you can add some options or features and contribute with it

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a very late response, This answer might be helpful. Highcharts-ng is a good option if you want to just use the chart for visualization purpose and you do not let the users of your application update certain properties of the charts. if you try to change any property of the chart other than the ones under "options", your entire chart will be redrawn. So, each time the user tries to update, the chart is going to be redrawn. 
Also, Highcharts-ng has issues handling large amount of data. Apart from these, Highcharts-ng is the best to use with angular.